# Facebook Graph API- Page post fetch in website

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I used following code to access facebook page posts.

```
$accessToken = 'EAAlGssgdgQIBAHuD9ZBZB6RWZClM3bmm8Vjv2nZBNmotTTnubgzdK4aiHbqJwhRlELjAurPEHKSqxJS7c0Pyd5ZBuqZAo2keabbkubx0AZCl3m6brDGlkXNgMq9dtNUZAx4P6QwdsXwNvJaEi2j3YDsHpZABiRxRK6qMAmZAyynLvJNCJ41ZBn9se28QUsDHG72mhZCzHFLpLQUxZCAZDZD';
$id = '109395947376896';
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/posts?access_token=$accessToken";
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$decoded = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($decoded);
```

and get the following result. screenshot is attached

[image]

how do I get images of posts??

Answer (score 0):

Without specifying the fields, you will only get default ones. This is how you can get fields (checkout the API docs for Posts about available ones):

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/$id/posts?access_token=$accessToken&fields=full_picture,message,...";
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/#fields

Answer (score 0):

You can get them in field parameters

- picture
- full_picture
- child_attachments

Also refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/